# Why do electrons move in a straight line in a Crookes Tube?

Tags: electrons, acceleration

(edit: I found it was already answered here [Maltese Cross Tube and the anode](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/242379/maltese-cross-tube-and-the-anode?rq=1), sorry about that.)

In a Crookes Tube, electrons are accelerated from cathode to anode, and overshoots the anode in a straight line.

[image: Crookes Tube]

The question would be: Why do the electrons in this case NOT follow the shortest path from cathode to anode?

Answer (score 0):

There is very little gas in the tube. So once an electron is freed from the cathode, it is unlikely to hit a gas atom, thus overall the electrons tend to travel in a straight line.

Comment: Thank you. Though my question mostly relates to the anodes electric field which will deflect electrons. But as I found out, it has already been answered here on SE.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I'm just new to stackexchange and I found it was already answered here [Maltese Cross Tube and the anode](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/242379/maltese-cross-tube-and-the-anode?rq=1)

Comment: See also this question <a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/535765/why-is-the-direction-of-cathode-rays-independent-of-the-position-of-anode"  >Why is the direction of cathode rays independent of the position of the anode?</a>